# Cannot install or deploy due to error "'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Tags: java, maven, gnupg

I am trying to deploy my java code, and generate Jar files so I can execute code through commands
What I did is I tried to Run the "deploy" option in Maves "deploy -f pom.xml"
I also tried the installatioin option "install" in Maves "install -f pom.xml"

Then process stopped and I got this error

> [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sign (default) @ ctakes ---
> 'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I have installed GnuPG, and added  `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG` to variables PATH

but still getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the system and try again. I think maven is not able to pick the updated `PATH` variable.

Try to run this command : `gpg --version`

Read [here](https://www.phildev.net/pgp/gpginstall#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Start%20%2D%3E%20Settings%20%2D,of%20the%20System%20dialog%20box.) about proper installation of GPG on windows.

Read [here](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c14.html) about creating secret key using gpg.

Comment: where did all the comments go?!